# MyEclipse can't load TLD file

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jsp-tags, myeclipse

I learn JSP in MyEclipse. But when i want to open a .tld file, MyEclipse appear an error.

> Plug-in com.genuitec.eclipse.j2eedt.ui was unable to load class org.jboss.tools.jst.web.ui.editors.TLDCompoundEditor.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtR2X.png)
MyEclipse version is 2017 CI 4
I search this in google but there is nothing.
What caused this error？？
How can I fix it？？
**Thank you!!**

Comment: Was there more information in the error log? There should be a reason for the inability to load the class.

Comment: Right click on file->Open With->Text editor